# Marginal PMF values of a function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've been doing this question and I was wondering if my workings are correct, if they are not correct, can you please correct them?

The question is as follows:
[image: question]

My workings are:

$\binom{y}{x} \frac{e^{-1}}{2^y y!}$

We can rewrite this:

$\frac{y!}{x!(y-x)!} \times \frac{e^{-1}}{2^y y!}$

$\frac{1}{x!(y-x)!} \times \frac{e^{-1}}{2^y}$

So we have:
$f_{x, y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{x!(y-x)!} \times \frac{e^{-1}}{2^y}$

Now using the formula:

$f_{x} (x,y) = \sum_{y}^{\infty} P_{x,y}(x,y)$

and subbing in $P_{x,y}(x,y)$:

$\frac{e^{-1}}{x!} \sum_{y}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(y-x)!}$

= $\frac{e^{-1}}{x!}$

And in a same fashion, for y we get:

$f_{y}(x,y) = \frac{e^{-1}}{y!}$

Comment: You need to specify for what values of $x$ (and $y$) those formulas apply. Note that the marginal pmfs are functions of just one variable, not two. By the way, have you noticed what _kind_ of random variables $X$ and $Y$ are?

Comment: How would I make it a function of 1 variable? What do you mean what kind? As in binomial random variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we find the  marginal pmf $f_Y(y)$ of $Y$. This is given by 
$$f_Y(y)=\sum_{x=0}^y \binom{y}{x}\frac{e^{-1}}{2^yy!}.$$
But the sum  $\sum_{x=0}^y \binom{y}{x}$ of the binomial coefficients is $2^y$.

It follows that $f_Y(y)=\frac{e^{-1}}{y!}$ for $y=0,1,2,\dots$.

For the marginal pmf $f_X(x)$ of $X$, we have
$$f_X(x)=\sum_{y=x}^\infty \binom{y}{x}\frac{e^{-1}}{2^yy!}.$$
By the simplification that you made, we have
$$f_X(x)=\frac{e^{-1}}{x!}\sum_{y=x}^\infty \frac{1}{(y-x)!2^y}.$$
Using $\frac{1}{2^y}=\frac{1}{2^x}\cdot \frac{1}{2^{y-x}}$, we obtain
$$f_X(x)=\frac{e^{-1}}{2^x x!}\sum_{y=x}^\infty \frac{1}{(y-x)!2^{y-x}}.\tag{1}$$
In (i), replace $y-x$ by $k$. Then 
$$f_X(x)=\frac{e^{-1}}{2^x x!}\sum_{k}^\infty \frac{1}{k!2^{k}}.\tag{2}$$
We recognize the infinite sum in (2) as the series expansion of $e^{1/2}$. Thus 
$$f_X(x)=\frac{e^{-1/2}}{2^x x!}$$
for $x=0,1,2,\dots$.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for that, it really helped. I didn't recognise the substitution step! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. In the second problem, it is replacing $2^y$ by $2^x\cdot 2^{y-x}$ that makes the problem collapse.

Comment: How about for Y? I don't know how to treat the (y-x)! part, I let u = y-x so I get (1/ (u!(u+x)!)) which doesn't work. Do you mind helping me with the marginal PMF of Y?

Comment: I did the marginal distribution of $Y$, it is the first part of the answer. (I did $Y$ first, violating alphabetical order, because it is much easier than $X$.) For $Y$, it is not profitable to use the fact that $\binom{y}{x}=\frac{y!}{x!(y-x)!}$, so I did not use it.

Comment: Silly me, I didn't see that! Wouldn't it be for y = x, x+1... as opposed to y = 0, 1, 2... ?

Comment: Note that the pmf of $Y$, the probability that $Y=y$, depends on $y$ only, $x$ has been eliminated by summing. If $y=0$, the sum is very short, it uses $x=0$ only. If $y=1$, we are adding the probabilities for $x=0$ and $x=1$. And so on. It really is $y=0,1,2,\dots$.

Comment: As a check, you can see that the sum of the $\Pr(Y=y)$ that I obtained, $y=0$ to $\infty$, is $1$, exactly what it must be.